# Why uuid in OpenMax is 128 bytes?

Tags: c, uuid, openmax

in OMX_Types.h there is

```
typedef unsigned char OMX_UUIDTYPE[128];
```

should I store every bit in a char?
if so, use actual number 0,1 or use ascii character '0','1'?

Comment: It seems to be a C-string so `'0'`, `'1'`, or better `snprintf(OMX_UUIDTYPE, sizeof(OMX_UUIDTYPE), "%d", your_number);` in case of UUID is a number only and no alphanumerical code.

Comment: my number is 128bit number like 0x4ac23030f4e06cb43ad9384123acc89f, so i cant use %d. guess i have to turn it into bits.

Comment: Surely you cannot input 128 digit into a 128 char array as string. You should have 129 array items to have room for a null terminator. BTW looking around on the web in some code libraries use strlen function on the type of varibles, so it is defenetly a string. [Manual](https://www.khronos.org/registry/omxil/specs/OpenMAX_IL_1_2_0_Specification.pdf) at page 64 says: _A very long unique identifier to uniquely identify at runtime. This
identifier should be generated by a component in a way that guarantees
that every instance of the identifier running on the system is unique._

Comment: So I suggest to use %d to put your number into that variable. Mandatory is that the number must be unique on the target system.

Comment: I make the uuid according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier